# Static Column and a variable as Row

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to find a way to use a variable number as row and leave a fixed column value, for example:

```
Dim Test As Long
Test = 15

Range("N & Test").Select
```

So I'll be able to change **Test** value and the code will change too but will keep the column value.

When I use the code above excel show me this error:

> "Run-time error '1004': Method 'Range' of object '_global' failed

---

----------------------------------First part resolved---------------------------

But what if I try to use this code like:

```
Sub MyVBA()

Dim myRow As Long

myRow = 10

    Set myRange = Range("A" & myRow)   ' **Worked!!!**
    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=$BA$13=""Y""" ' **Here’s the problem, what can I do in this case?**
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 14474460
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False


End Sub
```

Like, how can i put "myRow" inside of Formula1:="=$BA$13=""Y"""

Thanks again,

Comment: `Range("N" & Test).Select`

Comment: Now replace `Selection` with `myRange`

Answer (score 0):

```
dim myRow as long

myRow = <foo>

Set myRange = Range("N" & myRow)
```

BTW: avoid using `.Select` in your code, it will slow it down and may cause other difficulties

Comment: Thanks, but can you help me with the second part of the post? I just add it now :D

Answer (score 0):

You just got your speech mark (`"`) in the wrong place. Your two options are to use `Range` or `Cells`. Examples of both are below.

```
Sub TryThis()
    Dim test As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    test = 15

    MsgBox ws.Cells(test, "N").Address
    MsgBox ws.Range("N" & test).Address
End Sub
```